# How to delete this trash can icon Android 6.0

Tags: recents-screen

I have an Elephone P9000 and it has this annoying icon at the bottom that makes the most recent app disappear almost. How can I go and delete it? I have root.

Comment: If you could provide us with a screenshot it'd be super helpful.

Comment: [Nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) let's you resize icons. Settings > look and feel> normalise icon size. This is an easy option of you are willing to switch painters

Comment: I'm sure you're talking about "Clear all" button. I wonder if there is a way to delete that. It's easy if you're on custom ROM.